# Can mechanical waves exist in zero gravity?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, waves, newtonian-gravity, pressure, oscillators

Just got out of a test and there was this question asking of true/false:

> “A fluid presents pressure variation only when subjected to a gravitational field”

To which the alleged correct answer was “TRUE” probably due to Stevin's Law/Theorem.

The problem is, I made a small thought experiment of imagining a fluid inside a piston in space where gravitational field tends to zero, if I compress the piston and generate mechanical waves in the fluid ( longitudinal waves ) and these are supposed to be interpreted also as pressure variations… would I be correct to assume that a fluid can present pressure variation when gravity is zero?

Thanks in advance, it’s more of a thought experiment and I don’t have deep knowledge on theoretical physics to explain or justify my answer properly.

Comment: The astronauts on the ISS can talk to each other, so obviously sound waves are possible in microgravity.

Comment: Since it is explicitly asked for a gravitational field, then I would also say "False", because accelartion can produce the same effect as gravitation. So an accelarating spaceship - where there is no massive object around  - could still lead to a variation in pressure of a fluid. Or just consider a bottle of water rotating in space (which is also just another example for acceleration).

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the physics students' dilemma. Physics exam questions aren't about physics: they are about mathematical models of physics. And, usually, what model you're supposed to use is unstated: you have to decode it implicitly. Woe to your grades if you choose a more realistic model than the questioner intended.

Theorems are truths about mathematics, not physics. The are useful in physics only to the extent that the mathematics matches the physical situation. The match is never perfect, but if you let awareness of the imperfections creep into your exam answers, your grades will suffer. Of course, in the lab, the situation is reversed: nature does what it will, regardless of your calculations, so awareness of the limitations of your models is essential.

As @Michael Seifert notes in the comments, a relevant experiment is performed every day, and pressure waves are indeed possible without gravity.

Answer (score 1):

Stevin's law (the relationship between depth and pressure) is a law of [hydrostatics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrostatics), whereas [longitudinal waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longitudinal_wave) in a liquid are in the domain of hydrodynamics. As Michael Seifert's excellent example shows, longitudinal waves are certainly possible in freefall, and there is no reason to think they would not be equally possible in the complete absence of a gravitational field.

The question is poorly worded and ambiguous, since its interpretation depends on what is meant by "pressure variation".